# Failed to resolve Dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying add following dependency

```
compile 'com.github.HugoMatilla:AudioPlayerView:v1.0.1'
```

but getting following error

> Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.github.HugoMatilla:AudioPlayerView:v1.0.1 Show in
>   File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

https://github.com/HugoMatilla/AudioPlayerView

Can any one Help me how to fix that

Comment: Did you read the README? https://github.com/HugoMatilla/AudioPlayerView#include

Comment: @cricket_007.ya i already read

Comment: Please show your Gradle file, then (if below answer doesn't solve)

Comment: @cricket_007.I  have not tested his answer .because i am now in office.let me try first and if any issue or it works then i will back to you.Thanks brother

Comment: @cricket_007.i hope hist suggestion will work .because till now i never used maven.i usually using only compile dependency

Comment: The compile dependencies do use Maven. But they connect through JCenter. If you did read the README, then that says the same thing as the answer

Comment: @cricket_007.yup you are right

Answer (score 2):

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Above code goes in `build.gradle (Project: whatevername)`

```
compile:'whatever'
```

Above code goes in `build.gradle (Module:app)`

Comment: @Ger.Thanks.you mean i have to add maven in mbuild.gradle (Project: whatevername)

Comment: The url yes, but the 'compile:whatever' goes in the Module one

Comment: @Germax.Thanks today  i will try